# Why can't I generate javadoc for this specific project? No error message

Tags: java, api, logging, documentation, javadoc

I'm trying to generate some javadoc for some of my projects. The comments etc. is inside already, but when I click on

"Project -> Generate Javadoc -> ..." in eclipse

the javadoc simply doesn't get generated for one of my projects, while the others are fine.

It even tries to open the index.html file but since no one has been created i just get a not found message by my browser.

Since there is also no error output I don't know what the problem is or what I can do now to generate the javadoc for this specific project.

I remember that I had this problem once already, but sadly I cannot remember how I exactly solved it that time. Is it possible that this has to deal something with invalid characters?

Did someone of you ever experience this behaviour? What did you do to solve it? Have you any hints or tricks for me, how I can find out what stops the javadoc generation for this one project? Also, is there maybe a logfile or anything similiar, where I can see what error occured during the creation.

Thanks a lot for your help

EDIT: Or can I somehow activate creation output on the console to maybe find the error this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my problem.

I found out that I somehow(!) only get a console output of the java doc generation when I use the

"File -> Export -> Javadoc -> ..." way.

In the received error message I could figure out that there really was a character in one of my Arraylists that he couldn't process (although I have no clue why the javadoc generator should care about the code inside my methods).

Once i removed the invalid character, javadoc generation went fine.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

In case somebody comes across the same problem, this brought everything back to normal for me

I removed all the libraries ( Project, libraries ), cleaned the project so that all the missing dependencies would show as error, then added them and cleaned the profile again